# How can I import event data into Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I had two days of event tracking lost due to a trigger being changed.  I have the data in an excel file and need to import it into my GA reports.  Is this even possible? From what I have read, it seems that I could create a custom metric for the lost data and use a custom dimension that I already send with the event, as the key.  Does anyone have any insight into a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data Import does not change data that's already been collected (unless you have GA Premium, which can apply data via query time imports apparently), plus you cannot create hits with data imports, so you cannot create events retrospectively (plus I do not quite understand the last part of the question, if you haven't sent the event then you have not sent any custom dimensions attached to it; custom dimensions are only sent together with interaction hits).

If it were just a few hours you might experiment with measurement protocol hits and the [queue time parameter](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#qt), but even if the 4 hours max queue time are apparently not a fixed limit it will certainly not work for two days. Plus you would have a hard time to connect those hits to an existing session.

All in all I don't think there is a way to do this.